# Auto Refresh Out-GridView in PowerShell 3.0

Tags: powershell

I am trying to have the GridView that is created by PowerShell (v3.0) auto refresh on a timed basis.  Let take the following simple example:

```
Get-Process | Out-GridView
```

This displays a nice pretty form of all my running processes.  How can I get this form to automatically refresh ever 60 seconds?  As a bonus, can the form refresh and keep the previously selected sort column/order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Auto-refresh isn't supported by `Out-GridView`. `Out-GridView` takes the result from `Get-Process`(which in this code is only called once) and displays it in a gridview.

To get auto-refresh, you need to create your own custom form with custom update logic on a timer, or make a loop that closes the gridview and reopens it after x seconds. Like this:

test.ps1

```
param(
[int]$waitseconds = 60
)

while($true) {
    Start-Process -FilePath powershell.exe -ArgumentList "-WindowStyle Hidden -Command &{ Get-Process | out-gridview; sleep $waitseconds; exit }" -Wait
}
```

Usage:

```
test.ps1
```

or

```
test2.ps1 -waitseconds 5
```

Be aware that each time it refreshed the gridview will take focus on screen(appear on top).

To get all the features you want, you need to create your own form.

Comment: I was hoping that PowerShell had something more elegant.  This method causes each GridView window to jump around the screen, but you did answer the question I was asking with a working method and I really appreciate your response.

Comment: PowerShell has something more elegant. It has the .Net framework available so you could create a custom form and logic that suits your needs. However, Microsoft can't create a cmdlet for every possible situation. If you search around, someone may have created exactly what you need as a script or cmdlet in a module. :)

Comment: You could write your own cmdlet that does what you want; displays data in a winform or wpf app.